# How to get ListView ID when CheckBox is checked?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-checkbox

I currently have a custom ListView. Each item inside that ListView contains an ImageView, two TextViews and a CheckBox. Below is a screenshot of the list.

[image: Screenhot]

I am capture when the user clicks on the CheckBox with the snipped below, however, I need the _id of the item that was checked.

```
// Get the CheckBox view
CheckBox routine_quick = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_quick);

// Set checked value depending on the database results
if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quick")) == 1) {
    routine_quick.setChecked(true);
} else {
    routine_quick.setChecked(false);
}

// Create onClickListener
routine_quick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            // ADD QUICK TO DATABASE

        } else {
            // REMOVE QUICK FROM DATABASE
        }
    }
});
```

However, with this method, the only parameter I get is "View v".

I tried searching but I only find examples of how to set the checkbox to checked when the ListView is clicked.

How can I get the _id when the CheckBox is clicked? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: check this tutorial.... http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

int id = buttonView.getId();

if(isChecked){
   switch(id){
      case R.id.sprint:
      //add to database
      ...
   }
}
else{
  switch(id){
      case R.id.sprint:
      //remove from database
      ...
   }
 }
}
```

This should allow you to work with ID's. Hope it works.